# Ordering Results from Related Tables in Eloquent and the Session

Tags: sorting, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following in my Event model in Laravel 4. The reason I am using QueryBuilder and not Eloquent is I need to have links in each column header in my results table in my view, that when clicked, order the results in asc or desc based on that column.

The issue I'm having is, if I use Eloquent, it won't work as most of the data is pulled through via relationships to other tables, so Eloquent can't find the required columns/fields.

```php
public static function getEvents($perPage = 10)
{
    $order = Session::get('event.order', 'start_date.desc');
    $order = explode('.', $order);

    $columns = array(
        'events.id as id',
        'title',
        'locations.city as city',
        'suppliers.name as supplier_name',
        'venues.name as venue_name',
        'start_date',
        'courses.price as course_price',
        'type',
        'status',
        'max_delegates as availability',
        'tutors.first_name as tutor_first_name',
        'tutors.last_name as tutor_last_name',
        'contacts.first_name as d_first_name'
    );

    $events = DB::table('events')
        ->leftJoin('courses', 'course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
        ->leftJoin('suppliers', 'supplier_id', '=', 'suppliers.id')
        ->leftJoin('locations', 'location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
        ->leftJoin('venues', 'venue_id', '=', 'venues.id')
        ->leftJoin('event_types', 'event_type_id', '=', 'event_types.id')
        ->leftJoin('event_statuses', 'event_status_id', '=', 'event_statuses.id')
        ->leftJoin('tutors', 'tutor_id', '=', 'tutors.id')
        ->leftJoin('delegate_event', 'delegate_event.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->leftJoin('delegates', 'delegates.id', '=', 'delegate_event.delegate_id')
        ->leftJoin('contacts', 'delegates.contact_id', '=', 'contacts.id')->groupBy('events.id')
        ->select($columns)
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1])
        ->paginate($perPage);

    return $events;
}
```

If you look at my EventsController at the getOrder method:

```php
public function getOrder($order)
{
    Session::put('event.order', $order);
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

You can see I am storing the order in the session and then in my model using that to sort the order of results.

Is there a way to do this in Eloquent the way I need to?

Comment: Eloquent does not use joins for its relationships so I do not believe you'd be able to achieve the same ordering on any of the joined columns, nor would you get a single result with the results pre-joined.

Comment: Any idea how something similar could be achieved using Eloquent then, or would it have to be done using a frontend solution?

Comment: You could always convert the object to an array and use the appropriate php array sorting functions.  I'd also suggest checking out the jquery TableSorter plugin.  Would be much quicker and your javascript users would probably appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, tried tablesorter and it would have been great, except for the fact that because I have my object split in the view by week commencing, it messes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you can just add a join() to eloquent right?

So, as an example, if you have users and each user has some blog posts (i.e. user has_many blogs), you can output an eloquent model showing username and blog title, ordered by blog title, as follows:

```
user::join('blogs', 'blogs.id','=','users.blog_id')
      ->order_by('blogs.title', 'asc')
      ->select(array('users.username', 'blogs.title'))
      ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Hey Gaz, yeah got it sorted doing it exactly like this, well pretty similar. :-)